# Guess this green leaf and red stem plant

Tags: identification

Can someone help in identifying this plant 
It has green leaves and reddish type stem
Its only small now how big will it grow.[image]

Comment: what are the white flecks or bits I can see on the plant, in the tray beneath and a few on the surrounding hard surface - something you dropped, or insects?

Comment: It's water reflection from flash  just watered it while taking photo

Answer (score 1):

It is probably a New Guinea Impatiens. Note the sharp looking teeth on the leaf margin, plus the overall annual habit of the leaves from a small crown. Colouring is quite variable on NGI but it is quite common for the stems and petioles to be bright red, extending up into the main leaf vein, and the leaves readily turn bright green when given more than adequate fertilizer. It is pretty easy to find similar photos online showing the same colour patterns. To confirm this examine a stem, which will be quite soft and juicy, lacking any woodiness.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply . Will these have flowers all images showing flowers in google. Do you know any site which has small sapling of new guinea impatiens (NGI) without the flower? I have kept the plant already in the sun and it dried a lot I guess  (NGI) should not be kept in too much heat that's what I read online.Regarding ( To confirm this examine a stem, which will be quite soft and juicy, lacking any woodiness.) i did check it out but that stem(or branch) was too small maybe 1 inch it was soft and juicy

Comment: I will have to wait for a few months if it gets flowers then it might look like the online photos